# Spotify New iOS SDK (SPTRemoteApp and SPTSessionManger) in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, spotify

> As Spotify framework is upgraded and new classes like SPTRemoteApp has
>   been introduced, I got totally frustrated to integrate it in old app
>   as they have changed almost every thing. So I need help if someone can
>   tell me these following points how it works. Somehow I feel I can do
>   login part but about track list and its playback part seems not
>   properly understandable from the Spotify developer docs for iOS.
>
> 1. How to get login Url from new Spotify framework or how to login by clicking button without checking login URL content.
> 2. How to get playlist like previously we get playlist by calling this method

```
[SPTRequest playlistsForUserInSession:session callback:^(NSError *error, SPTListPage *object) {
        playListCount = [object.items count] - 1;
        if (object.items) {
            [object.items enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SPTPartialPlaylist *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                [playlistURI addObject:obj.uri];
                if (idx == object.items.count - 1) {
                    [weakSelf requestsTracks:playlistURI withSession:session];
                }
                spotifySynching = NO;
            }];
        }else{
            spotifySynching = NO;
            [self stopAnimatingTotalSpinner];
            [self updateProgressDisplays];
        }
    }];
```

> 3. How to maintain and renew session, nd when we should renew it.
> 4. What is the replacement of these methods

```
(SPTListPage *)object;
[object requestNextPageWithSession:session callback:^(NSError *error, SPTListPage *object) {
        [tracksURI addObjectsFromArray:object.items];
        if ([object hasNextPage]) {
            [self hasNextTrack:object withSession:session withNewObject:newObject];
        }else{
            [self requestsTracks:newObject withSession:session];
        }
    }];


   [SPTRequest requestItemAtURI:obj withSession:session callback:^(NSError *error, SPTPlaylistSnapshot *object) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"*** Auth error: %@", error);
            return;
        }

        [tracksURI addObjectsFromArray:object.firstTrackPage.items];

        if ([object.firstTrackPage hasNextPage]) {
            [self hasNextTrack:object.firstTrackPage withSession:session withNewObject:newObject];
        }else{
            [self requestsTracks:newObject withSession:session];
        }
    }];
```

Please check and let me know.
Thanks

Comment: I am also having trouble with this changes even the playback has changed. Now, you cant directly observe the playback position of the playhead